# count the top ten occurences in a table in a decreasing order

Tags: r

here is a  table

```
top10_bands <- table(bands1995$origin)
top10_bands
```

Where origin is the country and bands1995 is the original dataframe. How do I write code to just get top ten countries with the most occurences in decreasing order?

Comment: `sort(top10_bands, decreasing = TRUE)[1:10]`

Comment: `head(top10_bands,10)` in case there's the possibility of not always having 10+ counts.

Answer (score 0):

Using dplyr package...

```
library(dplyr)
    
    top10_bands <- bands1995 %>%
      group_by(origin) %>%
      summarise(n_bands = n()) %>%
      slice_max(order_by = n_bands, n = 10)
```